# RHEL 5 Yum Repository from DVD

Tags: yum, rpm, rhel-5

I have a Red Hat 5 system installed from a Official DVD.

At times, I need to install packages from the DVD at a later stage. Whenever I need to do that, I have install RPMs one at a time through a painful process of dependency resolution.

**Question:**

> How does one configure YUM so that i can conveniently install packages from the DVD.

**Notes:**

- there is [createrepo](http://linux.die.net/man/8/createrepo) but I can't get group information for multiple folder along with it, say, for group installing `Development Tools`
- online CentOS repositories are no good as our corporate proxy blocks access to some essential files fetched during an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/redhat-centos-fedora-linux-setup-repo.html) explains how to set up a repository from a DVD/CD or ISO.

[This page explains how to set up an mrepo repository](http://blog.sumostyle.net/robg/2006/05/28/adding-new-rpm-packages-to-a-fedora-dvd-with-compsxml/), it seems that it will generate a comps.xml file which you will need to do groupinstalls.  Perhaps that does what you need?

Comment: thanks... like i mentioned in the question... this method leaves out group information for multiple repositories in the same DVD... look at the notes...

Comment: thanks again... the posted link explains how to add additional RPMs to a install DVD / ISO to make them available during an install... the mention of `comps.xml` is for adding the RPMs (to be added to the ISO) to a new group which can be checked off during installation... interesting, but it doesn't answer my question...

Answer (score 1):

After some digging I've found there are two convenient ways of doing this:

---

**Method 1:**
For single repositories, the best way to go about it is to use this command:

> [system-cdinstall-helper](http://linux.die.net/man/8/system-cdinstall-helper)
>       provides a graphical interface for installing packages from the yum repository located at **URL**.

This method only allows for installing packages from a single repository.

---

**Method 2:**
For adding multiple repositories, the way to go about it is to add the **URL** of the repository in `Add/Remove Software`.

Both methods automatically pick up all group information in the repositories. One can locate repositories by looking for a folder named `repodata` in its root, this directory holds all the metadata for the repository.